# Why $x^{(1/2)2} \neq x^{2(1/2)} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I know, probably is a newb. question, but i can't get this $x^{(1/2)2} \neq x^{2(1/2)} $ $ x\in\mathbb R^+$.

I know $x^{(1/2)2}=(\pm \sqrt{x})^2=+x $

and $x^{2(1/2)}=\pm x $ because $(+x)^2=(-x)^2=x^2$.

**Edit** so  $\pm x \neq +x$

so...maybe multiplication is not commutative and $(1/2)2 \neq 2(1/2)$, or maybe $\sqrt[n]{x}\neq x^{1/n}$... or $(x^n)^m\neq x^{n\times m} $ in other words it isn't a multiplication.

Maybe im wrong when I think that $\log_x(x^y)=y$ ($\log_x$ isn't multivalued for $x,y>0$ or not?) and

$x^{(1/2)2} \neq x^{2(1/2)} \rightarrow (1/2)2 \neq 2(1/2)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you getting this? What is $x$? What is $r$?

Comment: $r$ is the square root of $x$. yes you are right the question is not very clear, I try to edit it and put more informations.

Comment: The equation is true when $x>0$, but doesn't hold for $x<0$ since the square root of a negative number is not well-defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what your definitions are.

Usually, $f : x \mapsto x^2$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^+$, and $g : x \mapsto x^{1/2}$ is a function from $\Bbb R^+$ to $\Bbb R^+$.

So, $f \circ g$ is defined on $\Bbb R^+$ and forall $x \in \Bbb R^+, f(g(x)) = f(\sqrt x) = \sqrt x \sqrt x = x$.
On the other hand, $g \circ f$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ and forall $x \in \Bbb R, g(f(x)) = g(x^2) = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.
$g \circ f$ is an extension of $f \circ g$ to $\Bbb R$.

So, if $x\ge 0$; it is true that $(x^{1/2})^2 = x^{(1/2)2} = x^1 = x^{2(1/2)} = (x^2)^{1/2}$.
If $x < 0$, then $(x^{1/2})^2$ doesn't make any sense but the other equalities are still valid.

In general, the rule $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b = (x^b)^a$ is only valid for real positive $x$ and real exponents $a$ and $b$ ; or for real or complex $x$ and integers exponents $a$ and $b$. Using it blindly in other cases is dangerous.

Comment: I was thinking $g$ as a "function" (bivalued) from $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R$: as the solution of the equation $x^2=a$  $a>0$, the solutions are $\pm x$...yea I understand there is something related to the restriction of the domain that you did for $x$ ...but there is something i cant see..maybe i try in another way (but maybe is the same way and i can't understand it)...why $x^a$ has one value if $a$ is integer and has many values if $a$ is not integer (for example $\sqrt[n]{a}$ has $n$ values in $\mathbb C$ right? )? I am very confused.

Comment: @MphLee, a function _by definition_ has one value only.

Comment: @MphLee : the square root $\sqrt x$ of a positive real number $x$ is defined to be the positive square root of $x$. Also, $x^a$ for strictly positive $x$ and real $a$ is defined as $\exp(a \log x)$. Thankfully, they agree on $\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$. Similarly, the logarithm of a complex numbers picks only one value instead of infinitely many ones, and exponentiation is defined the same way. Wanting to use multivariate relations and then compose them is an ungodly bad idea that will only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong because 
$$x^{2 (1/2)}=x^1= x$$ 
Something related is that  in general 
$$(a^n)^m\neq a^{nm}$$
(when $a$ is negative for example, or when $n$ or $m$ are complex)

In general
$$\sqrt[n]{x^m}\neq x^{\frac{m}{n}}$$
and $$
\log(x^y) \neq y \log(x)$$
as $x<0$