# Why is $|x| \neq x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was just thinking about the absolute value function. Why does the following equality not hold?

$$|x| = \sqrt{x^2} = (x^{2})^{1/2} = x^1 = x$$

After all, there are clearly some values of $|x|$ that are not equal to $x$. Is this a domain/range issue?

Comment: The square root function returns a positive number, your third equality does not hold.

Comment: Power rules are universally true only for positive values of the basis.

Comment: Some general advice: plug in a value of $x$ that doesn't work (say $x = -1$) and see where the chain of equalities fail. It will help you determine where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't hold is because the third equality is not true. I can't use $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ in this context, because $x$ is not necessarily positive. I made reference to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/343945/98587), which aptly states:

> In general, the rule $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b = (x^b)^a$ is only valid for real positive $x$ and real exponents $a$ and $b$ ; or for real or complex $x$ and integers exponents $a$ and $b$. Using it blindly in other cases is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

$$\sqrt{x^2} = (|x|^{2})^{1/2} = |x|^1 = |x|$$

Answer (score 0):

Because your third equality is not true. If you take the square root of a square, you must include absolute values because the square has already mapped the function to the positive reals, which is why you do not have a domain issue with the square root in the first place.

Comment: this is the third equality, not fourth ;)

Comment: Pff. I do math. Who ever said I could count?

Comment: Wow... people are harsh with type'os